# How to join a research group when not affiliated to any institution

Tags: research-process, career-path, independent-researcher

I have just completed my bachelor, and wish to pursue a masters in the field of robotics. However, during my bachelors, I was not able to build a good research profile and do not have any publications in my name.

Therefore, I would like to join a project group in a university and work under the guidance of a professor to build my research profile.

I have a two-part question.

1. Is such a thing even possible.
2. Is yes, how to approach professors for the same.

I understand this might not be the best place to ask, but since everyone in this community is related to academia in some capacity, your guidance would really mean a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible and called “volunteer research assistant”. Write to professors and ask to get research work experience. You might even get paid.

Keep emails short and send as many as you can. Don’t worry if you don’t get response, professors might miss your letter. When writing, mention specific projects or papers by that professor.

I am currently working with one undergrad and one 1st year PhD student. Previously I've worked with high-school students and undergrads.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I will give it a try

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is very difficult to achieve unless you bring some special expertise or talent that the professor would find valuable in their work. You are, in essence, I fear, asking for an education and use of the professor's time and knowledge without actually being part of their institution. It is all cost and little to no benefit for the professor.

Professors, on the other hand, might be interested in collaborations among people, even students or independents, as long as there is some common skill-set and understanding of the problems to be solved. Your status as independent has no bearing in this case. But what you know and what you can contribute is very important.

Some professors, if they hold a research grant in robotics might be able to hire technicians to help in the work but they need skills and probably won't learn too much on the "research side".

So, it is difficult to encourage you.

However, it might be possible to take a course or two as a non-matriculated student prior to applying for a masters. And, in some places, such as the US, research skills aren't normally required for entry into graduate programs. Building a "good research profile" is difficult in many places.

And, if you have the skills and background to convince a professor to work with you on research, you probably have the skills and background for successful admission to a masters (or even a doctorate in the US).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers.  I do get your point